# How to use join and group to get highest amount of specific records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Models:
person.rb

```
# Table name: people
#
#  id                         :integer          not null, primary key
#  pesel                      :string           not null
#  first_name                 :string           not null
#  last_name                  :string           not null
```

work_schedule.rb

```
# Table name: work_schedules
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  start_time  :time             not null
#  end_time    :time             not null
#  day_of_week :string           not null
#  person_id   :integer          not null
```

Associations:
person.rb

```
has_many :work_schedules, dependent: :destroy
```

work_schedule.rb

```
belongs_to :person
```

What I try:

```
@day_most_work = WorkSchedule.includes(:person).group('work_schedules.id, work_schedules.day_of_week').order('COUNT(work_schedules.day_of_week) DESC').first.day_of_week
```

Issue:
I don't have idea how to create correct query to get day_of_week which most people are associated. E.g. 23 people work on Monday, 54 people work on Friday. Query should return Friday(more employeers than on Monday). I think my query is incorrect because if 
I change DESC to ASC return same day(in my case Monday). Most working day cannot be the least working day in same time. This query I create in action of controller.

Comment: are you trying to find how many people are working on each day?

Comment: @TallPaul I think he wants to find out which day of the week that has the most people work on

Comment: @lusketeer you have right

Comment: @TomekWejchorowski kinda rough, give this a shot? `WorkSchedule.group(:day_of_week).select("day_of_week, COUNT(id) as work_count").order("COUNT(id) DESC").first.work_count`, if you don't care about unique count of the person, this should do the trick

Comment: @lusketeer thank you very much! now it works! It was really simply. I don't know why I wanted to include people table.. I have to low reputation to give +1 for comment. Sorry.

Comment: @TomekWejchorowski no worries, good luck